# Nodejs Coffescript executing without translation and coffee command

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Is here any way how to execute Coffescript script in Nodejs without translation to js or coffee command.

Something what will translate coffeesctipts on the fly, how will node request them.

Comment: I've never heard of one, and frankly I think your chances of finding one are dim

Comment: What do you want? Give an example. Do you want to type `node hello.coffee`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, do `npm install coffee-script`, then in your server.js (or app.js) do `require('coffee-script')` and any coffeescript files will automatically be compiled.

This tutorial series goes into how to include coffeescript files so they will automatically be recompiled when they are edited:

http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/16-introduction-to-coffeescript-and-nodejs.html#video

http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/14-some-nodejs-tools.html#video

Answer (score 0):

If your code is 100% coffee, you might want to check [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

I am currently writing my code directly in coffescript, then to run my server instead of doing `node <server-file>coffee`, I just run:

`nodemon <server-file>.coffee`

Answer (score 0):

You use a tiny JS file that has only 2 lines:

```
require('coffee-script/register');
require('my_program.coffee');
```

You run this tiny JS file directly with Node.
In turn, it loads, compiles, and runs your coffeescript code.
Then you can modify your coffeescript program and re-run it without any separate compile step -- just re-run the JS file.